# How to use the gtsummary package for ordinal multiclass logistic regression

Tags: r, gtsummary, gt

I am trying to use the `tbl_uvregression` function of the `gtsummary` package for batch univariate analysis, the function of the analysis is the `polr` of the `MASS` package ordinal multi-classification.

```
library(gtsummary)

tbl_uv_ex2 <-
  tbl_uvregression(
    housing[c("Infl", "Type")],
    method = polr,
    y = Sat,
    exponentiate = TRUE,
    pvalue_fun = function(x) style_pvalue(x, digits = 2)
  )

str(housing)
```

[image]

Comment: Please update your post with a _minimal_ reproducible example, i.e. the minimal amount of code to illustrate your issue with code/data we can run on our machines. It would be helpful to include code to build a single model.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example as @DanielD.Sjoberg has suggested. You can even use dummy data. He is the developer of gtsummary package. I am sure you will get the most authentic solution for your issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you passed the housing data frame to the function, you excluded the outcomes, `Sat`, leading to the error that `object 'Sat' cannot be found`.

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(MASS)

tbl_uvregression(
  housing,
  include = c(Infl, Type),
  method = polr,
  y = Sat,
  exponentiate = TRUE,
  pvalue_fun = ~style_pvalue(.x, digits = 2)
) %>%
  bold_labels() %>%
  as_kable()
#> 
#> Re-fitting to get Hessian
#> 
#> Re-fitting to get Hessian
```

| **Characteristic** | **N** | **OR** | **95% CI** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Infl** | 72 |  |  |
| Low |  | — | — |
| Medium |  | 1.00 | 0.35, 2.84 |
| High |  | 1.00 | 0.35, 2.84 |
| **Type** | 72 |  |  |
| Tower |  | — | — |
| Apartment |  | 1.00 | 0.30, 3.34 |
| Atrium |  | 1.00 | 0.30, 3.34 |
| Terrace |  | 1.00 | 0.30, 3.34 |

<sup>Created on 2022-10-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>